# How to initialize 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm building a tictactoe game, but I can't seem to figure out how to initialize a 2d vector.  I know how to do this for a 1d vector, and I assumed a 2d vector would operate on the same principles, but this code doesn't work:

```
vector<vector<int>> PossibleWins[8][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

I've tried a few variations of this, but I'm not having any luck.  The compiler says `no viable conversion from int to vector<vector<int>>`

Comment: "*I know how to do this for a 1d vector*" Well, judging by your code, the 1d case would be `vector<int> PossibleWins[8] = ...`. And that's *not* how you'd do it for the 1d case.

Comment: Lose the `[8][3]` and the `=`.

Comment: You have a 2D array of vectors of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> PossibleWins {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
vector<vector<int>> PossibleWins[8][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

The compiler thinks everyone of those numbers represents a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. It complains since the numbers cannot be used to initialize `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Compare that with how you would initialize a 2D array.

```
int PossibleWins[8][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

That works since each of the numbers is an `int`.

To initialize a vector of vectors to represent a 2D array, you need to use

```
vector<vector<int>> PossibleWins{{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

Answer (score 0):

how about doing like this

```
vector< vector<char> > board = { {'U','R','L','P','M'},{'X','P','R','E','T'},{'G','I','A','E','T'},{ 'X','T','N','Z','Y' },{ 'X','O','Q','R','S' } };
```